# c# output possible routes

Tags: c#, algorithm, combinations, combinatorics

I have an dynamic array, containing for example `(int) {1, 2, 3}`

I would like to generate the following:

`123
132
213
231
312
321`

(note the sorting)

I was thinking of building 3 loops for the above, but that solution doesn't come up well when the array length is 16 for example, and I need a dynamic solution.

Can you help? Thank you. This is for a personal project.

Comment: what would be the expected output if the input is {1,1,2,3}

Comment: What did you try? Is there a specific problem? This site will not write your code for you.

Comment: Like I said, I thought of multiple loops, but that doesn't seem right to use since the length of the array is not constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Permutations Extension Method](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/branches/EvenMoreLINQ/MoreLinq/Permutations.cs) from the excellent [EvenMoreLINQ project](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/#svn/branches/EvenMoreLINQ).

*Example:*

```
foreach (var p in new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Permutations())
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", p));
}
```

*Output:*

```
1, 2, 3
1, 3, 2
2, 1, 3
2, 3, 1
3, 1, 2
3, 2, 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about listing all permutations of an array in lexicographic order. Lets assume first we have a permutation and we want to generate one that goes next lexicographically. Here are the steps we have to take (here `a` goes for an array variable, ):

1. Find the largest `i` for which `a[i] < a[i+1]`.
2. Find the largest `j` for which `a[i] < a[j]`.
3. Swap `a[i]` with `a[j]`.
4. Reverse elements between `a[i+1]` and `a[n-1]` (including both).

Now starting from the first permutation (which is basically a sorted array), we can produce all permutations one by one, using these steps every time, until we failed to find `i` in the first step. When this happens, it means that we just produced the lexicographically last permutation.

**Update**: Here is the code sample - function that takes an array representing a permutation and generates (and prints) the next one lexicographically.

```
/// <summary>
/// Generates and prints next permutation lexicographically.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="a">An array representing a permutation.</param>
/// <returns><c>true</c> if next permutation was generated succesfully, <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
public bool PrintNextPermutation(int[] a)
{
    int i = a.Length - 2;
    while (i >= 0 && a[i] >= a[i + 1]) i--;

    if (i <0)
    {
        // it was the last permutation
        return false;
    }

    int j = a.Length - 1;
    while (a[i] >= a[j]) j--;

    int temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;

    Array.Reverse(a, i + 1, a.Length - (i + 1));

    foreach (int item in a)
    {
        Console.Write(item + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I started writing the code, but seems I got stuck about the structure, and some actions I should make. Can you make a small example? Thanks